# How to change the size of circlecollider2d for X amount of time

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to use my circlecollider2d as a sort of force field to push objects back for a given amount of time, on button press. Here is the code I have, to simply turn it on and off again.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = 25.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = 2.1f;
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the above code working and you just want to know how to increase the collider for a certain amount of time instead?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Invoke` to call a function after x number of seconds. I modified your code below to clear the force field 5 seconds after it is activated.  The `forceFieldActive` flag will prevent it from being activated again while it's already active.

```
int forceFieldDuration = 5; //5 second duration
bool forceFieldActive = false;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && forceFieldActive == false)
    {
        forceFieldActive = true;
        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = 25.0f;
        Invoke("DisableForceField", 5);
    }
}

void DisableForceField()
{
    GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = 2.1f;
    forceFieldActive = false;
}
```

**Note**: You can also use a coroutine which is more efficient as Draco18s mentioned in the comments. It would look like this:

```
int forceFieldDuration = 5; //5 second duration
bool forceFieldActive = false;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && forceFieldActive == false)
    {
        forceFieldActive = true;
        GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = 25.0f;
        StartCoroutine(DisableForceField());
    }
}

IEnumerator DisableForceField()
{        
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(forceFieldDuration);
    GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = 2.1f;
    forceFieldActive = false;
}
```

Comment: Invoke has a lot of overhead. A coroutine would be better.